# Rails Hosting - Is RailsPlayground.com a Good Host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud-hosting

My team is currently looking into hosting for RoR apps, and we're considering RailsPlayground, Linode and SliceHost.

We haven't found anyone recommending rails playground, and web of trust seems to caution against it - http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/railsplayground.com

I like the fact that they give you a sourcerepo account for free to host and track git repos, etc.

The Questions:

- **Is there any reason not to go with RailsPlayground?**
- **Have you had any negative experiences with RailsPlayground? (Feel free to share positives as well)**

Thanks!

Comment: Completely honest/ignorant question, did you consider heroku and if so what ruled them out?

Comment: Yes - we considered heroku, but the prices are too expensive for our budget - we're currently using heroku for testing with their free account. With linode for example, you get a VPS for $20, but with heroku for example, the first database jump from 5mb to 20gb is $15

Comment: Closing as off-topic as  [we don't do shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi im using railsplyaground shared hosting for our apps .. to me its "OK" in terms of value vs quality. They have very good customer support and minimum downtime (99% uptime).

However did you consider rackspace for cloud solution? they have a good service and nice control panel for you servers ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you confident administrating your own system?

If you are, I can't see any reason not to just get a linode (I'm with vr.org- they're excellent and ip6 connectivity was a big plus for me) or whatever, and configure it as you see fit.. set up your own git repo.